# Search for a string in name and move file according to it

Tags: csv, powershell

I am trying to import a **CSV file** and loop through all entry to search for a match ( file names will also have other string in name), afterwards, I want it to put the match in the appropriate directory, which is named after the CSV file

**For Examples:**

*Files I have:*

Rapport PTP (12314)

Test (124523)

*I want:*

./12314/Rapport PTP (12314)

./12314/Rapport PTP (12453)

My CSV file contains all the numbers that needs to be searched through a directory.

EDIT: So far I have came up with this, but for some reasons it just gives false...

```
Set-Location "d:\PTP" 

$Folders = Import-Csv D:\data\Documents\buse1.csv
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\PTP 

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
 foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    $contains = $File.Name -like "*$($Folder.Name)*"
    if ($contains) {
        $Destination = 'd:\test1\{0}' -f, $folder.name;
        mkdir -Path (Split-Path -Path $Destination -Parent) -ErrorAction     SilentlyContinue;
        Move-Item -Path $folder.Name -Destination $Destination -WhatIf;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: So, the number in the filename is the same as a number you have from the CSV?

Comment: yes, sorry if I wasn't clear. @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what trips up your logic:

```
$File.Name -contains $Folder.Name;
if($contains){
    # ...
}
```

`-contains` works on collections (arrays, lists, enumerables), but doesn't do a substring search:

```
PS> "Long","string" -contains "string"
True
PS> "Long string" -contains "string"
False
```

Use `-match` or `-like` when doing string comparison instead:

```
$File.Name -like "*$($Folder.Name)*"
```

or:

```
$File.Name -match [regex]::Escape($Folder.Name)
```

---

Furthermore, `$contains` doesn't exist - you need to assign the result of the comparison to it for your `if()` statement to work:

```
$contains = $File.Name -like "*$($Folder.Name)*"
if($contains){
    # We got a match!
}
```

or perform the comparison *inside* the `if()` statement:

```
if($File.Name -match [regex]::Escape($Folder.Name)){
    # We got a match!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I believe I have fixed the logic, it seems like it has trouble creating the file. any idea why? I have managed to get it to create the files. I should figure out how to copy the files there now. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Your `mkdir` and `Move-Item` statements in the sample script you provided doesn't make sense - you create the parent folder of a folder you already know to exist, then move the folder into the same parent folder where it already exists in the first place